# Detect 2 Touch Pan vs 1 Touch Pan on UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a UIImageView inside. I have the UIScrollView set to scroll only with a 2 finger pan gesture, that works fine. Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in _imgScrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
            panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
            panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        }
    }
```

I would like to capture 1 finger panning with touch events(touchesBegan:, touchesMoved:, touchesEnded:) and pass these events to another UIView that is directly under the UIScrollView.

The reason I want to do this is because the other UIView is a drawing view where the user can draw lines. This drawing view does not use a pan gesture recognizer to draw lines, just simple touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded methods. The user should be able to scroll around the image with 2 fingers and draw with 1 finger, this is the end goal functionality.

I realize that other questions have asked something similar to this but I haven't been able to find one with a conclusive answer on how to handle 2 finger pans and 1 finger pans separately. Here's my viewDidLoad method where I implement the scrollView:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imgScrollView.delegate = self;
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [_imgScrollView addSubview:imgView];
    _imgScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _imgScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in _imgScrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
            panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
            panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.